# Why does Mojolicious have two methods to access POST body?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

The Mojolicious has two methods to access POST body: [`body_params`](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojo/Message#body_params) and [`json`](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojo/Message#json)

What is the benefit of them?

**UPDATE**
I think, it will be more handy if `body_params` returns hash if body is recognized by some parser and `body_type` will return the name of this parser.
Thus if it were POST from form `body_type` will return `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: Plagiarised here: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1198846

Comment: @choroba: huh... someone repost my question one on one (((

Comment: They did, and not only yours, and then reposted good answers back to get XP. World is a weird place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot tell you why this decision was made. You'd have to ask SRI for that. [He added](https://github.com/kraih/mojo/commit/1dbb37dfdf6397be03f6036b4986664e681955b0) the `json` method in 2010.

But I can tell you why it is useful.

`body_params` parses requests for common form submissions, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `multipart/form-data`. You use that when your action talks to an HTML form submission or similar.

`json` on the other hand automatically decodes JSON data from the body. This is useful for AJA<strike>X</strike>J requests and APIs. Typically it's used in a REST context where the client sends JSON encoded information. It decodes the JSON directly, making your live easy for you.

Comment: Yes, but why controller should worry about format of request? The life will be more easy if I just get request data. Now, instead, I should write: `$data = $req->json || $req->body_params->to_hash`. And things goes worse if application allow many request formats.

Comment: @EugenKonkov you could write your own handler that deducts the format and deals with it. Then you can pass cleaned up data to your controllers and reuse that for all of them. But if you wanted your app not to care about the incoming format, I'd have the controllers deal with the format and have a fat model for the business logic.